# will swapping ssd on laptop with installed drivers work?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, laptop, drivers

So I have a 512gb ssd currently on my laptop with windows 7 and all the drivers installed. I want to switch to 1tb ssd and install windows 10 and all the drivers in it. but if I do decide to go back to the 512gb with windows7, will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work for sure, **but is not advised**. A chance of hard drive clash may occur though unlikely. If possible, adding the second 1 tb hard drive to your laptop is better than replacing it. You can still dual boot if you do this so you can choose between Windows 7 and Windows 10.